# Почему класс с get- и set- методами работает без метода main?

Tags: java

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int balance;
    private int monthsOfEmployment;
    private String companyName;
    private int salary;
    private String currency;

    public User(String name, int balance, int monthsOfEmployment, String companyName, int salary, String currency) {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.monthsOfEmployment = monthsOfEmployment;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.currency = currency;
    }


    void paySalary() {
        balance += salary;
    }

    double withdraw(int summ) {
        double withdraw;
        double commission;
        if (summ < 1000) {
            commission = summ * 0.05;
        } else {
            commission = summ * 0.1;
        }
        withdraw = summ + commission;
        double bal=(double)balance;
        bal=bal-withdraw;
        return bal;
    }

    void companyNameLengt() {
        System.out.println(companyName.length());
    }

    void monthIncreaser(int addMonth) {
        monthsOfEmployment += addMonth;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getMonthsOfEmployment() {
        return monthsOfEmployment;
    }

    public void setMonthsOfEmployment(int monthsOfEmployment) {
        this.monthsOfEmployment = monthsOfEmployment;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

Comment: что именно работает без main? И как вы узнали что что-то работает без main? И где тут создание класса?

Answer (score 4):

Метод `main` является *точкой входа в приложение* и обязателен он (да и вообще необходим) только для, так называемых, `Main`-классов, которые указывается в конфигурации проекта.

Непосредственное выполнение программы начинается с метода `main(...)`, указанного в конфигурации `Main`-класса. Класс `User`, очевидно, таковым классом не является, поэтому в нем нет необходимости реализовывать метод `main(...)`.

Comment: Тогда для чего в этом коде нужен System.out если этот код ничего не выводит в консоль?

Comment: @FatalError метод вызывают на экземпляре класса, который где-либо создается. Очевидно же. Когда и где - не имеет значения. Соответственно когда экземпляр будет создан, значит там точно был метод main и было запущено приложение с консолью

Answer (score 0):

Статический метод класса `main()` служит для запуска Java программы извне, примерно так:

```
$ java my.package.MyClass
```

При этом, если в классе `MyClass` будет объявлен `public static void (или int) main(String[] args)` (сигнатура может слегка меняться), то Java запустит этот класс. Все остальные классы (включая те, у которых есть сеттеры и геттеры -  методы `setXXX()`, `getXXX()`), могут быть использованы в при работе этого запущенного класса. Итого: наличие или отсутствие методов `getXXX()` и `setXXX()` методов **никак не влияет на возможность запуска класса извне**.